# Python3.5-dev in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python3

I installed python3.5.5 from source using make altinstall.
Now I also need python3-dev. However I can not find any info on what version I need to work with 3.5.5.
If I google python-dev version for Ubuntu 18.04 it always points me to versions in the apt that are labeled 3.6.x but I assume I need a 3.5.x python-dev.

Comment: by typing `apt search python3.5-dev` : *python3.5-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4 amd64  [installed, automatic]
  Header files and a static library for Python (v3.5)* on an Ubuntu 16.04. You can installed `python3.5-dev` by typing `sudo apt install python3.5-dev`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python3.5-dev I don't have 16.04 I have 18.04, so your solution won't work for me.

Comment: did you try `apt search python3.5` ? Sure, all package from 16.04 and 18.04 aren't same, but python3.5 or more are on 18.04

Comment: Like I said, when I used apt search python3.5-dev all I got was: E: Unable to locate package python3.5-dev

Answer (score 8):

try this one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

I found this at: [Install Tensorflow 1.8.0 with GPU from source on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver](https://medium.com/@Oysiyl/install-tensorflow-1-8-0-with-gpu-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-35cfa9df3600), hope this work for you :)